# DTW - What is fan-in nodes and why not just take the nearst points from each timeserie?

Tags: time-series, distance

It has been a while that I am trying to understand the dtw (dynamic time warping) algorithm but I steel can't figure out the loginc behind this algorithm..

In many references it's explained that to compute the path between to time series I need to implement this recursivity:

[image]

I have many questions here and I hope some one can give me an answer:

1. What we mean exactly by the *path* between two time series ?
2. What is the (cost path matrix described here:

[image]

3. Why not just compute the distances between a given point of `t` and other points of `r` and select the closest one an repeat this until matching all points from `t` to points from `r` ??

Thanks in advance for any helpfull answer / comment.